# GPU Picking in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working with the GPU picking example in Three js. Can someone explain how we retrieve the object from the picking texture.  I don't understand how the code works.

```
//create buffer for reading single pixel
            var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array( 4 );

            //read the pixel under the mouse from the texture
            renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(pickingTexture, mouse.x, pickingTexture.height - mouse.y, 1, 1, pixelBuffer);

            //interpret the pixel as an ID

            var id = ( pixelBuffer[0] << 16 ) | ( pixelBuffer[1] << 8 ) | ( pixelBuffer[2] );
            var data = pickingData[ id ];
```

I understand  that we're getting the pixel value from the texture, but unclear as to how we then reference the object using the ID

Comment: So what you're actually doing is reading the color value under the cursor.  If you were to render pickingTexture, you'd see it was all the boxes with slightly different RGB values.  Those values correspond with the IDs, and you can figure out what object you clicked on.